# Error in Insert function in postgresql

Tags: postgresql-9.1

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION InsertInformation  
(  
    p_Name varchar(20)  
    ,p_Address varchar(250)  
    ,p_Mobile int  
) RETURNS VOID  
    as $$
    begin   
    declare v_ID int;
    BEGIN

select  coalesce(max(Id),0) into v_ID from Information  
set; v_ID=v_ID+1  

insert into Information  
(  
    Id  
    ,Name  
    ,Address  
    ,Mobile  
)  
values  
(  
    v_ID  
    ,p_Name  
    ,p_Address  
    ,p_Mobile  
)  
select v_ID;
$$ 
LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

I convert my sql insert sp to Postgres function using online converter tool but it showing the below mention error

error showing : ERROR:  syntax error at or near "insert"
LINE 16: insert into Information

Comment: "*using online converter tool*" whatever that tool is, stop using it. It apparently doesn't do a good job. You *have* to read the Postgres manual to understand and the learn the SQL and PL/pgSQL syntax. Otherwise your migration will never work, neither with an automatic tool nor manually (and an automated tool that generates invalid syntax is even worse)

Answer (score 0):

This:

```
select  coalesce(max(Id),0) into v_ID from Information  
set; v_ID=v_ID+1
```

Is wrong.

The `select` isn't properly terminated, and the `set` itself is illegal syntax.

You probably want this:

```
select  coalesce(max(Id),0)
    into v_ID 
from Information; --<< terminate with a ; here
v_id := v_id + 1; --<< terminate with a ; here
```

But the extra assignment isn't necessary in the first place. The above can be shortened to:

```
select  coalesce(max(Id),0) + 1
    into v_ID 
from Information;
```

This

```
select v_ID;
```

is also wrong. To return a value use:

```
return v_id;
```

But your function is defined as `returns void` so you can't return anything in the first place.

---

**But**: using  `select coalesce(max(Id),0) + 1` to generate unique IDs is wrong and will ***not*** work correctly in a real world application.

The **only** correct, scalable and fast way to generate new ids is to use a sequence. Really.

---

The complete function (if you want to return the newly "generated" id) would look like this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION InsertInformation(p_Name varchar(20),p_Address varchar(250),p_Mobile int) 
  RETURNS integer  
as 
$$
declare 
  v_ID int;
BEGIN

  select coalesce(max(Id),0)  + 1 
     into v_ID 
  from Information;

  INSERT INTO information
    (id, name, address, mobile)
  VALUES
    (v_id, p_name, p_address, p_mobile);

  return v_id;
END;

$$ 
LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

SQLFiddle example: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/4ac27/1

Comment: i am migrating from mssql to postgresql ....i am converting my mssql query in online convertor , the above code is converted one.

Comment: @sams: I already commented on that quality of that online converter. But regardless of converter: using `max(id) + 1` to "generate" IDs is something you should **never** do - you shouldn't have done that in SQL Server either.

Comment: still showing error...i am going for refer syntax of postgresql and continue my work